Как найти объем пересечения двух тетраэдров?

Я нашел статью в которой описан алгоритм поиска пересечения двух тетраэдров
https://www.unige.ch/~mccoid/ongoing/Intersection_of_tetrahedra.pdf
Но не нашел реализации, поделитесь пожалуйста

Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

На geometrictools.com не смотрели? Определение факта пересечения там было, а есть ли нахождение самого полиэдра - я не копался.

Задача сводится по сути к определению объёма тела, образованного пересечением произвольного количества полупространств

Один тетраэдр превращаем в набор полупространств. Из второго берём грани по одной. Для одной грани все полупространства пересекаем с плоскостью грани. Получится треугольник и четыре полуплоскости - это всё на плоскости. Треугольник отсекаем полуплоскостями: получится многоугольник или вырожденный многоугольник или пустое множество. По многоугольнику в плоскости восстанавливаем многоугольник в пространстве.
Итого для каждой грани второго тетраэдра построен многоугольник в пространстве. Меняем тетраэдры местами, строим ещё четыре многоугольника для граней первого тетраэдра.
На каждом из восьми многоугольников строим пирамиду с вершиной в глобальном нуле. Для такой пирамиды есть формула объёма со знаком - получается из формулы объёма тетраэдра со знаком. Складываем все объёмы пирамид - сумма есть объём пересечения двух тетраэдров.

Не было бы проще итеративно пересечение тетраэдра и полупространства разбить на тетраэдры?

@VladD, "тетраэдризация" многогранника совсем не простая задача. Аналогия с триангуляцией на плоскости не работает.

@VladD, я старался в решений уйти от многогранников в пространстве. Это позволяет решить задачу более элементарными средствами. Все вычисления, кроме финального вычисления объёма делаются на плоскости.

По идее для пересечения тетраэдра и полупространства есть три случая: меньший тетраэдр, усеченный тетраэдр, и сечение, разделяющее две вершины и две другие вершины (плюс вырожденные случаи). Эти три случая «тетраэдризируются» тривиально, а дальше итеративно продолжаем добавлять полупространства

Усечённый тетраэдр (ака треугольная  призма) требует известной изобретательности (три тэтраэдра, если не ошибаюсь). Но вы правы - случаев конечное число, все можно разобрать. Пишите ответ. Если подумать, вполне реализуемая идея.

Угу, там три тетраэдра: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Prism_on_Triangular_Base_divided_into_Three_Equal_Tetrahedra (в тексте для случая параллельных направляющих, но рисунок подходит и для усеченного тетраэдра)

Заодно получаем лёгкий способ тетраэдризации произвольного выпуклого многогранника

Кстати, если грани у нас есть, то тетраэдризация выпуклого многогранника не должна быть сложной. Триангулизируем все грани, и соединяем треугольники с произвольной точкой внутри, получаем искомые тетраэдры (инспирировано вашим методом нахождения объёма). Для уменьшения количества тетраэдров в качестве произвольной точки можно взять одну из вершин.

@VladD, вы правы, действительно простой и универсальный способ.

Поскольку один из тетраэдров можно представить себе в виде пересечения полупространств, ограниченных его гранями, задачу можно свести к поиску пересечения тетраэдра и полупространства, и разбиения полученного тела на тетраэдры.
Исходный первый тетраэдр пересекаем с первым полупространством, пересечение разбиваем на тетраэдры, каждый из этих тетраэдров пересекаем со вторым полупространством, получившиеся фигуры снова разбиваем на тетраэдры, получаем новый набор тетраэдров, и к ним применяем ту же процедуру итеративно, пока не закончатся полупространства. Объём каждого из итоговых тетраэдров можно найти, например, как смешанное произведение векторов его сторон.
Итак, нам нужно сообразить, какое может быть пересечение тетраэдра с полупространством. Рассмотрим следующие случаи.

Все вершины тетраэдра лежат вне нашего полупространства, тогда наше пересечение — пустое множество. Этот случай тривиален.

Все вершины тетраэдра лежат в нашем полупространстве, тогда наше пересечение — весь тетраэдр. Этот случай также тривиален.

1 вершина тетраэдра лежит в нашем полупространстве. Мы имеем в пересечении тетраэдр DPQR, так что разбиение на тетраэдры тут тоже тривиально.




3 вершины тетраэдра лежат в нашем полупространстве. Это тот же случай, но теперь нас интересует нижнее тело ABCQRP. Оно разбивается, например, на тетраэдры ABCP, ACPR и APQR.

Остался случай, когда две вершины лежат в нашем полупростанстве, а две другие — нет.



Мы получаем тело CDPQRS. Отделив от него тетраэдр CDRS, получаем четырёхугольную пирамиду DPQRS, которая делится на тетраэдры DPQS и DRQS.
(Вырожденные случаи, когда одна из вершин лежит на плоскости, можно отнести к тому или другому случаю.)
Таким образом, мы можем получить разбиение исходной фигуры на тетраэдры, и найти нужный объём.
